# Measuring time spent in function per second

Tags: windows, scheduling

I know what you think, but I believe this is not a duplicate question. On Windows Vista and newer, take a function like:

```
void spin()
{
    while(TRUE);
}
```

How can I measure the total time spent executing this function in the last second? The problem is of course that I don't want to include the time being scheduled out, only the time spinning -> the part of the last second that was spent in this loop. I hope it makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is it [GetThreadTimes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237(v=vs.85).aspx). The interesting parameter is the UserTime in this case, although if you call kernel in your function I suspect adding KernelTime would not be a good idea since you can always get some extra tics that aren't really yours if your thread is interrupted. It would be also nice if MS stated whether these times are updated on context switches (they probably are but I want to hear it).